Inconveniente usando ConfirmDialog and Toasts de BlazorBoostrap junto a EditForm
buenos días. Espero me puedan ayudar.
Contextualizando, estoy desarrollando un sitio web Blazor WebServer utilizando .Net8.
En el proyecto FrontEnd he intentando utilizar el componente ConfirmDialog y Toasts de Blazor Boostrap (https://demos.blazorbootstrap.com/), presentádose un incoveniente que no he logrado resolver.
Si lo ejecuto desde un componente cualquiera, funciona perfectamente:
Ejemplo:
    @page "/counter"
    @rendermode InteractiveServer

    <PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

    <h1>Counter</h1>

    <p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount1">Click Toasts</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount2">Click ConfirmDialog</button>

    @if (toastParametros.Visible){<_Toast toastParametros="toastParametros"></_Toast>} 

    <ConfirmDialog @ref="confirmDialog" />


    @code {
        private int currentCount = 0;
        private ToastParametros toastParametros = new ToastParametros(); 
        private ConfirmDialog confirmDialog;

        private void IncrementCount()
        {
            currentCount++;
        }
        private void IncrementCount1()
        {

                toastParametros.Type = ToastType.Info;
                toastParametros.IconName = IconName.Alarm;
                toastParametros.Title = "title";
                toastParametros.Message = $"info saved.";

                toastParametros.Visible = true;
        }


        private void IncrementCount2()
        {

             var confirmation = confirmDialog.ShowAsync("Confir", "¿save the changes?");

        }
    }

El problema se presenta cuando utilizo EditForm, pues ni ConfirmDialog y Toasts se hacen visibles, a pesar de que han sido convocados.
Cuando se realiza click sobre el boton save, el navegador queda como "cargando".
Ejemplo:
           @page "/prueba"


    <EditForm Model="Model" OnSubmit="HandleSubmit" FormName="New">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />

        <!-- Form Fields Here -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <Button Color="ButtonColor.Success" Size="ButtonSize.Medium" Type="ButtonType.Submit" >
                    <Icon CustomIconName="fas fa-save" /> Guardar
                </Button>
                <Button Color="ButtonColor.Secondary" Size="ButtonSize.Medium" Type="ButtonType.Link">
                    <Icon CustomIconName="fas fa-times" /> Volver
                </Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </EditForm>

    <ConfirmDialog @ref="dialog" />

    @code {
        private ConfirmDialog dialog = default!;
        private Cliente Model = new Cliente();

        private async Task HandleSubmit(EditContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                if (context.Validate())
                {
                    var confirmation = await ShowConfirmation();
                    if (confirmation)
                    {
                        await Insert(Model);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> ShowConfirmation()
        {
            var options = new ConfirmDialogOptions
                {
                    YesButtonText = "OK",
                    NoButtonText = "Cancelar"
                };

            return await dialog.ShowAsync("Confirmar", "¿Confirma los cambios?", options);
        }

        private async Task Insert(Cliente cliente)
        {
            // Your insert logic here
        }


        public class Cliente
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }
    }

Cualquier ayuda o guia, ha de ser bienvenida. Saludos

¿Estas seguro que estas pasando la validación context.Validate()?.
Te sugiero 2 cosas:

Usa OnValidSubmit en EditForm, así solo llegarás a tu código de submit cuando el formulario sea válido.
Podrías mostrar el dialogo dentro del catch, quizás estas pasando directo por ahí y por eso no se ejecuta la llamada al diálogo. Suerte!

